# Make a GtkMessageDialog movable?

Tags: rust, gtk

Is it possible to make a GtkMessageDialog set as a modal movable/draggable? I'm using Rust with Gtk-rs (GTK 4) but this does not need to be language specific.

More details:
I'm using Linux (Fedora 36) with GNOME. Here is a link to the code: https://github.com/lakoliu/Furtherance/blob/f19023ce3917efde04ff37fb77c00f6bd56b2c13/src/ui/window.rs#L319

Comment: Maybe share information about your setup? Works fine for me on macos using https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk4-rs/blob/master/examples/dialog/main.rs

Comment: @frankenapps Interesting, that seems similar to what I have. I updated my post with more details. What I would really like is for the main window to be draggable while the MessageDialog is stuck to it as a modal.